# how to use .rdlc parameter in report's query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I'm passing a parameter to my .rdlc file, which is working properly.  What I can't figure out is how to then use that parameter in the query the reports dataset uses.  How can I use this parameter in the query?

I'm designing it in Visual Studio 2008.  If there is some other method I'm not aware of, please suggest that also.  I want to keep the report as un-coupled with the program as possible so I can reuse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only answer I can find is that this is not how reporting services works.  You must give it a dataset at runtime which has the same schema as the dataset used at design time.

I was expecting (and hoping for) a similar behavior to Crystal Reports, where you can open a stand-alone report file and be prompted for parameters, and then embed that same report into an application and pass it parameters programatically.  Reports are more portable that way, but if its not possible...